# Stack smashing detected C++

Tags: c++, g++

I am writing a little program. I have working build on my Windows. I rewrite exact copy of this program on my Ubuntu. But in Ubuntu i get stack smashing error every time i execute my program. In both OS i use Codeblocks IDE. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


double max_elem(double a, double b)
{
    if (a <= b )
        return a;
    else return b;
}
double  min_elem(double a,double b)
{
    if (a >= b )
        return a;
    else return b;
}
double result (int pawn_v, int pawn_h, int knight_v, int knight_h)
{
    double result_array[7];
    for (int i=0; i<=7; i++)
        result_array[i] = 2;
    double a,b,c,d;
    pawn_h++;

    if (pawn_h>8)
        return 1;
    else if ((pawn_v == knight_v + 2) && (pawn_h == knight_h + 1))
        return -1;
    else if ((pawn_v == knight_v + 2) && (pawn_h == knight_h - 1))
        return -1;
    else if ((pawn_v == knight_v - 2) && (pawn_h == knight_h + 1))
        return -1;
    else if ((pawn_v == knight_v - 2) && (pawn_h == knight_h - 1))
        return -1;
    else if ((pawn_v == knight_v + 1) && (pawn_h == knight_h + 2))
        return -1;
    else if ((pawn_v == knight_v + 1) && (pawn_h == knight_h - 2))
        return -1;
    else if ((pawn_v == knight_v - 1) && (pawn_h == knight_h + 2))
        return -1;
    else if ((pawn_v == knight_v - 1) && (pawn_h == knight_h - 2))
        return -1;
    else if ((pawn_v == knight_v) && (pawn_h == knight_h))
        return (0.5f);
    else
    {

        result_array[0] = result(pawn_v, pawn_h, knight_v + 2, knight_h + 1);

        result_array[1] = result(pawn_v, pawn_h, knight_v + 2, knight_h - 1);

        result_array[2] = result(pawn_v, pawn_h, knight_v - 2, knight_h + 1);

        result_array[3] = result(pawn_v, pawn_h, knight_v - 2, knight_h - 1);

        result_array[4] = result(pawn_v, pawn_h, knight_v + 1, knight_h + 2);

        result_array[5] = result(pawn_v, pawn_h, knight_v - 1, knight_h + 2);

        result_array[6] = result(pawn_v, pawn_h, knight_v + 1, knight_h - 2);

        result_array[7] = result(pawn_v, pawn_h, knight_v - 1, knight_h - 2);

        a = max_elem(result_array[0],result_array[1]);
        b = max_elem(result_array[2],result_array[3]);
        c = max_elem(result_array[4],result_array[5]);
        d = max_elem(result_array[6],result_array[7]);
        return (max_elem(max_elem(a,b),max_elem(c,d)));
    }
}
int main()
{

    char knight_start, pawn_start;
    int knight_start_horizontal, pawn_start_horizontal, knight_start_vertical, pawn_start_vertical;

    scanf("%c%d%*c%c%d%*c", &pawn_start, &pawn_start_horizontal, &knight_start, &knight_start_horizontal);
    knight_start_vertical = int(knight_start)-96;
    pawn_start_vertical = int(pawn_start)-96;

    if (pawn_start_horizontal==2) {
        if (min_elem(result(pawn_start_vertical,pawn_start_horizontal,knight_start_vertical,knight_start_horizontal),result(pawn_start_vertical,pawn_start_horizontal+1,knight_start_vertical,knight_start_horizontal))==0.5)
            printf("%.1f", 0.5);
        else printf("%0.f",min_elem(result(pawn_start_vertical,pawn_start_horizontal,knight_start_vertical,knight_start_horizontal),result(pawn_start_vertical,pawn_start_horizontal+1,knight_start_vertical,knight_start_horizontal)));
    }
    else
    {
        if (result(pawn_start_vertical,pawn_start_horizontal,knight_start_vertical,knight_start_horizontal)==0.5)
            printf("%.1f",0.5);
        else printf("%.0f", result(pawn_start_vertical,pawn_start_horizontal,knight_start_vertical,knight_start_horizontal));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can i prevent this error?

Comment: Knight_start_vertical is chess vertical. It can be [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]. Using this lines i can transform char into numbers, according to ASCII table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have working build on my Windows. I rewrite exact copy of this
>   program on my Ubuntu. But in Ubuntu i get stack smashing error every
>   time i execute my program.

First of all, stating the name of your operating system is not enough. There is **more than one compiler** available on any of those systems. Not to mention that "Windows" could, in theory, be everything from Windows 1 to Windows 10 and that "Ubuntu" is hardly a very precise definition, either. And that compilers have different versions and endless combinations of different invocation options.

Second, if by "stack smashing error" you mean a segmentation fault, the program crashes "on Windows" as well. I just tried it on MSVC 2013 on my Windows 7 64-bit machine with `/EHsc /Za`. It crashed after I tested it with some more or less random input (I just entered 12, 2 and 2).

> How can i prevent this error?

By avoiding what C++ calls **undefined behaviour**. In contrast to certain other languages, C++ sometimes leaves the behaviour of the program to the compiler or to the operating system when you make critical programming errors, such as trying to access memory you are not supposed to access. Crashes or seemingly random crashes are one possible manifestation of undefined behaviour.

As far as I can see, you have two instances of undefined behaviour in your code. Note that the first is already enough to render the entire program invalid.

> ```
> double result_array[7];
> for (int i=0; i<=7; i++)
>     result_array[i] = 2;
> ```

`[7]` means that this is an array with 7 elements, but the indices of those elements are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. In the last iteration of your loop, `i` is 7, so you try to access `result_array[7]`. This is undefined behaviour.

> ```
>    d = max_elem(result_array[6],result_array[7]);
> ```

Again, `result_array[7]` is undefined behaviour.

Now, as far as your `main` function is concerned...

> ```
> char knight_start, pawn_start;
> int knight_start_horizontal, pawn_start_horizontal, knight_start_vertical, pawn_start_vertical;
>
> scanf("%c%d%*c%c%d%*c", &pawn_start, &pawn_start_horizontal, &knight_start, &knight_start_horizontal);
> ```

`scanf` is an old C function particularly hard to use correctly, because you have to manually ensure that the types of the arguments match type identifiers in the format string. You will inevitably make undefined-behaviour-causing programming errors when you use it. In this case, you actually seem to have used it correctly, although personally my mind after all those years still has huge trouble parsing a half-way complex C format string, so don't take my word on it. And I don't understand why you use the assignment-suppressing `*` parts.

You can make this infinitely clearer and safer by using C++ streams:

```
std::cin >> pawn_start;
std::cin >> pawn_start_horizontal;
std::cin >> knight_start;
std::cin >> knight_start_horizontal;
```

Or, what would be even better: Use `std::getline` to read an entire line of input into a `std::string` and parse that one, such that you can respond to wrong user input with error messages like *"pawn start horizontal must be a number".* There are hundreds of questions and probably thousands of answers about this on Stackoverflow.

While you're at it, consider using `std::cout` instead of `printf`.

I'd say go and fix the undefined behaviour with your array and use safe I/O. If it then still doesn't work, ask a new question, because the problem then likely lies elsewhere, but as long as there is undefined behaviour, it does not make sense to further reason about the program's logic.